# Implicitly run Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, msbuild, nunit

Please see the DOS command below:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe WindowsFormsApplication1.csproj /t:Test
```

The .csproj file looks like this:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
        <NUnit3-ToolPath>C:\Development\C#\UnitTests\UnitTests\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.1\tools</NUnit3-ToolPath>
 </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Test">
    <NUnit3 ToolPath="$(NUnit3-ToolPath)" Assemblies="C:\Development\C#\UnitTests\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll" OutputXmlFile="test-results.xml" />
  </Target>
```

If I exclude: `/t:Test` from the DOS command then the build succeeds even if the unit tests fail. How do I ensure the unit tests are run when this command is run:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe WindowsFormsApplication1.csproj
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about NUnit unit tests (and not MSTest unit tests)?

Comment: @Alex, thanks.  Yes, I am.  I have added a tag to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was just to add an AfterTargets attribute as follows:

```
 <Target Name="Test" **AfterTargets="Build">**
     <NUnit3 ToolPath="$(NUnit3-ToolPath)" Assemblies="C:\Development\C#\UnitTests\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll" OutputXmlFile="test-results.xml" />   </Target>
```